# Opening multiple chromedriver on start of selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Although test is executing one after another but two chromes are launching initially instead of one after another one.

```java
package dOUBT;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TEST {
    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();          
    @Parameters({ "URL"})
    @Test()
    public void login(String URL)  {        
        try {
                driver.get(URL);
                System.out.println("Website opened");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Below is my `testng.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1">
    <test name="GOOGLESmoke1">
        <parameter name="URL" value="http://google.com"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="dOUBT.TEST"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="YAHOOSmoke2">
        <parameter name="URL" value="http://yahoo.com"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="dOUBT.TEST"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Can you please share your full code ?

Comment: its full code only.u can copy one code in a java file and another in testng.xml it will work

Comment: Where you are setting chrome.exe file pathin your code ?

Comment: there are lot of ways to launch chrome .. if u copy paste chrome driver in project location also it will work

Comment: There is no closing tag `</suite>` in the xml file. Missed while copying? If not, then this xml is wrong.

Comment: No in your code where you are using ?Can you please share full code

Comment: xml is correct and result is passing also. issue is only 2 chrome launching in beginning

Comment: @ ankur singh added jars details also. u can copy it directly and check the issue

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"); where is this line of code in ur script

Comment: @ankur singh  this line of code is not mandatory to write ..unless u have not kept chrome driver in project location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public class TEST {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @Parameters({"URL"})
    @BeforeTest
    public void b(String URL){
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get(URL);
    }
    
             
    @Test()
    public void login(){        
        try {
                //verification code
                System.out.println("Website opened");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: tHANKS it worked perfectly on adding of before test tag.Upvoted your answer